# Why does this produce a value restriction exception?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, f#-interactive

I've created a function that returns a list containing only the even indexes as shown below:

```
let rec removeOddIdx xs =
    match xs with
    |[] -> []
    |h::t -> (if t.Length % 2 = 0 then 
                [h]@removeOddIdx t
                else 
                removeOddIdx t)
```

It works fine when I call it:

```
removeOddIdx [1;2;3;];;
```

However when I call it with an empty list:

```
removeOddIdx [];;
```

I get a Value Restriction exception - how come?
I've read up on value restrictions but I don't understand why it happens in my case.

Here is the precise error message:

> Testing.fs(13,1): error FS0030: Value restriction. The value `'it'` has been inferred to have generic type
>
> `val it : '_a list`
>
> Either define `'it'` as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it, but I did't get any exceptions, compiler errors, or warnings.

Comment: That's strange. Every time I run it I get the error (updated the thread with the error text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the compiler doesn't know what type to give the return value.  When you pass it `[1;2;3]` it can infer that the return type is `int list`, but if you pass it `[]`, what is the type of the return value?  It cannot be inferred from the usage, so you get a value restriction error.

One solution is to give the parameter a type like so:

```
> removeOddIdx ([]:int list);;
val it : int list = []
```

The other is to make the function specific rather than generic like this:

```
> let rec removeOddIdx (xs:int list) =
    match xs with
    |[] -> []
    |h::t -> (if t.Length % 2 = 0 then 
                [h]@removeOddIdx t
                else 
                removeOddIdx t);;

val removeOddIdx : xs:int list -> int list

> removeOddIdx [];;
val it : int list = []
```

Outside of the repl this is unlikely to be an issue since the parameter type is likely to be inferred from elsewhere in your code.